# Name hiding in constructor initialization list

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, this, name-hiding

I want to modify a constructor to use an initialization list as in the following example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo(std::wstring bar);
private:
   std::wstring bar;
};

// VERSION 1:

Foo::Foo(std::wstring bar) {this->bar = bar}

// VERSION 2:

Foo::Foo(std::wstring bar) : this->bar(bar) {} // ERROR!
```

Unfortunately I can't do version 2 because you can't use the `this` pointer for data members since (I'm guessing) they don't exist yet at that point. How then, do I deal with the name hiding issue (i.e. my parameter and my data member have the same name)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to. The first `bar` will refer to the member and the second `bar` will refer to the argument:

```
Foo::Foo(std::wstring bar) : bar(bar) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would change the name of the argument so it's clear which is which.

```
Foo::Foo(std::wstring b) : bar(b) {}
```

Note that you don't strictly have to, but future maintainers of your code will probably thank you.

**Alternate option:**

It's common in C++ to denote private member variables with a special naming convention, for example a trailing underscore.  That solves this problem nicely:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo(std::wstring bar);
private:
   std::wstring bar_;
};

Foo::Foo(std::wstring bar) : bar_(bar) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this:

```
Foo::Foo(std::wstring bar) : bar(bar) {}
```

Everything initializer used after the `:` must refer to either a base class or some member. That means your `bar` member won't be hidden at that point.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will know what to do... just remove this->