# What happens when constructor's parameter has same name as member variable?

Tags: c++

I am trying a code which goes like this:-

```
class Something
{
private:
    int data;

public:
    Something(int data)
    {
       data = data;
    }
    int getdata()
    {
        return data;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Something xyz(5);
    cout<<xyz.getdata()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is "0".
i am stuck why this is coming as 0.
kindly help.
TIA.

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this problem?

Comment: replaced the line data=data by this->data = data and it works fine.

Comment: i mean to ask why 0 is coming.
since = operator has right to left associativity then data must be resolve first and the new data should be 5.

Comment: new data value in this case: 'this->data', not 'data'.

Comment: it should be like this:-
Something(int data)
 {
       data = 5;
 }

But when you print the data it gives 0.

Comment: Use the member initializer list: `Something(int data) : data(data) {}` The compiler sorts out which is which.

Comment: @LaluParshad: give more tries without fix with different compiler and OS. And I am sure that you will see some garbage value instead of 0.

Comment: @rahul.deshmukhpatil even the random value doesn't explain the behaviour.

Something(5){  data = 5 ; }

Comment: @LaluParshad Associativity has nothing to do with it. It is purely and simply a scoping problem. The parameter hides the member variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name hiding in constructor initialization list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716337/name-hiding-in-constructor-initialization-list)

Answer (score 3):

You can change the definition to

```
Something(int data):data(data)
{
}
```

and it will work, too.  The parameter `data` hides the field `data` in the scope of the function.  `this->data` explicitly specifies the scope to be that of the class.  I can't tell you why the above declaration works other than to say that the elements in the initialization list of the constructor must be fields of the class instance.  So this may imply the scope.  While the values with which they are initialized come from the function scope.