# How to use identical constructor parameters and field name?

Tags: c++, constructor

Why this code showing uninitialized/garbage value? It's showing correct value when the field name and constructor parameters not identical.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Employee {
public:
     Employee(string name,string company,int age)
     {
         name = name;
         company = company;
         age = age;
     }
     string name;
     string company;
     int age;
     void IntroduceYourself()
     {
         cout<<name<<' '<<company<<' '<<age<<endl;
     }

};
int main()
{

    Employee employee1= Employee("Saldina","Codebeauty",25);

    employee1.IntroduceYourself();

    Employee employee2 = Employee("John","Amazon",35);

    employee2.IntroduceYourself();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `name = name;` is doing? How should a compiler make a distinction between data member name and function parameter name?

Comment: It is ambiguous as to which variable is being set, class variable or local variable. If you want to use same field names, use this keyword in the constructor e.g. this->name = name;

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: What does this keyword do actually? Does it refer to the class variable ?@AjitVaze

Comment: @Roman It refers to the object you're working with.

Answer (score 2):

If we declare a name in an inner scope, that **name hides uses of that name declared in an outer scope**.

The `name` which is a function parameter hides the `name` which is a data member. How would you tell which of the `name` is meant to be on which side in here:

```
name = name
// data_member = parameter ?
// parameter = data_member ?
// parameter = parameter !
// data_member = data_member ?
```

Thus, your output, the `IntroduceYourself`, prints two empty strings and a default initialized `int`, since in the body of the constructor you reassign values to the parameters, local variables, while the data members are default initialized.

There are two common approaches:

```
// Not the best practice, but can take place 
 Employee(string name,string company,int age) { 
     this->name = name;
     this->company = company;
     this->age = age;
 }
```

And:

```
Employee(string name, string company, int age) 
    : name(name), company(company), age(age) {} // Compiler will sort it out
// Data members
string name;
string company;
int age;
```

Note, that you should use the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), as in the second example. Otherwise, you default initialize data members and then reassign new values to them, when you *"initialize"* them in the body of a constructor.

Comment: thanx for your answer buddy.

Comment: Can I use same name in the 2nd approach ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959703/what-happens-when-constructors-parameter-has-same-name-as-member-variable  

But here seems to be same name .

Comment: Don;t you use memeber initializer list in the 2nd approach?

Comment: @Roman Yeah, That's true! Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185020/initializing-member-variables-using-the-same-name-for-constructor-arguments-as-f/6185043#6185043).